# does `git pull --rebase` impact the Working Directory?

Tags: git

I understand that `git pull --rebase` will sync from Remote Repository to Local Repository, and rebase accordingly afterwards.

However, after `rebase`, if Local Repository is changed, will the change (new files added etc) be copied to the Working Directory?

Comment: Yes. (11 more to go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as the pull docs say:

> git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch. With --rebase, it runs git rebase instead of git merge.

A merge or rebase will affect your working tree.

Comment: It doesn't touch the working *tree*. Technically the "working directory" would have the `.git` directory as a subdirectory, which would be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` is nothing but a shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD` i.e. all the changes from the remote directory will be copied to the local directory.

If you use `git pull --rebase`, then the `git merge` command will be replaced by `git rebase` i.e. when you are using `git pull --rebase` then it is a shorthand for `git fetch` and `git rebase`. So, it will rebase the local repo.

Comment: understand that `git pull --rebase` equals to `git fetch` then `git rebase`, but which part caused the working directory to be updated, `git fetch` or `git rebase`?

Comment: `git fetch` will just download all your commits, files and refs from the remote repo. The updation part in your local repo is done by `git rebase`.